# How to add all minutes between two dates to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to add all minutes to a list between two dates
so for example if the first hour is 1 and the second is 3 , I want the list to contain `[1:00:00,1:01:00,1:02:00,....2:58:00,2:59:00]`.

I know how to collect specific date using "datetime" but is there a function or something to collect time between two dates

Comment: Do you know how to check if a single time is between two other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 0)
end_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 3, 0)

dates_range = []
while start_date < end_date:
    dates_range.append(start_date) # or you can append str(start_date) if want the dates to be as strings
    start_date += timedelta(minutes=1)

print(dates_range)
```

Comment: thank you! it is correct